# "Favorite tag" highlighting too subtle

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design

Just wondering if we can make the colouring of the "Favorite tags" row highlight a bit more obvious. It's barely visible on one of my monitors and not at all on my laptop screen.

Currently it's set to `rgba(255, 245, 222, 0.4)` and pushing the alpha up to `0.7` or above makes it readable for me.

I could change it locally with a user style, but I'm guessing if I'm having the issue, then others probably are too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your monitor's gamma is a bit off. But I do realize a lot of people have this problem, especially on older LCDs. I have bumped up the alpha to 0.6 if it helps. The change will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Absolutely agree its an issue with my monitor(s). But as you say it's a common issue and unavoidable for me (dual screening two very different monitors). Thanks for the adjustment.